# Listing the people who earned less than the average?

Tags: java, arrays, average

The question i'm having is that is there anyway I can compare the final average salary and then go through the loop again and compare the Final average salary to each salary and determine who is lower and print that person out and do that for everyone i'm having trouble trying to figure that out here is my code. Should i put the people in another array list and compare from there?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Kuroii on 11/3/2014.
 */
public class BelowAverage {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String inputFile = "c:\\Users\\Kuroii\\documents\\javafiles\\sampletwodata.txt";
        String strline,FirstNames="",SurNames="",EMPnumbers="";
        int totalSalary=0,averageSalary=0,salary=0;
        //

        ArrayList<String> inputLines = new ArrayList();
        try {
            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            BufferedReader inputBuffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            System.out.println("Starting...");
            while ((strline = inputBuffer.readLine()) != null) {
                inputLines.add(strline);
            }
            System.out.print("Read in ");
            System.out.print(inputLines.size());
            System.out.println(" lines");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("MB Error reading input file");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < inputLines.size(); i++) {
            String delim = "[ ]+";
            String[] fields = inputLines.get(i).split(delim);
            String wage = fields[3];
            String hours = fields[4];
            FirstNames = fields[1];
            EMPnumbers = fields[5];
            SurNames = fields[2];
            salary = Integer.parseInt(wage) * Integer.parseInt(hours);
            totalSalary =totalSalary + salary;
            averageSalary = totalSalary/inputLines.size();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just told the algorithms with words. Putting it into Java code is just a scribe work

Comment: I think it's best to define a new `class` to hold the information on each person, and then set up an `ArrayList<Person>`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make a class called `Person` or `Employee`, which has descriptive variable names such as `Salary`
2. Make a collection of `Person`.  call it `people`
3. Calculate the average Salary.  You can do this by summing all the salaries, and dividing it by the number of people.
4. make a new collection and insert into that collection people only if they have a lower salary than average

Comment: When did Java start supporting LINQ?

Comment: @ajb I hate it when I do that

Comment: FYI, Java 8 can do something similar to what you were trying to do in C# ... http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/DoubleStream.html#average--